# Find duplicate in linear time and space

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming

The task:

> You are given an array of length n + 1 whose elements belong to the
>   set {1, 2, ..., n}. By the pigeonhole principle, there must be a
>   duplicate. Find it in linear time and space.

```
const lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7];
```

My functional solution:

```
const findDuplicate = lst => {
  const set = new Set();
  let ret;
  lst.some(x => set.has(x) ?
           !Boolean(ret = x) :
           !Boolean(set.add(x))
  );
  return ret;
};

console.log(findDuplicate(lst));
```

My imperative solutions:

```
function findDuplicate2(lst) {
  const set = new Set();
  let i = 0;
  while(!set.has(lst[i])) { set.add(lst[i++]); }
  return lst[i];
}

console.log(findDuplicate2(lst));

function findDuplicate3(lst) {
  for (let i = 0, len = lst.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (lst[Math.abs(lst[i])] >= 0)  {
      lst[Math.abs(lst[i])] = -lst[Math.abs(lst[i])];
    } else {
      return Math.abs(lst[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(findDuplicate3(lst));
```

Comment: (How about sketching an O(1) space solution?)

Comment: @greybeard isn't `findDuplicate3` O(1) space? I don't use an additional variable - only the running variable `i`.

Comment: Announced as `imperative solution`, I didn't expect nor notice more than one - even eye-balling it has to wait till after "day-time chores".

Comment: @greybeard but I don't know whether it's good practice to mutate the input value.

Comment: sorry for nitpicking, but a set – by definition – is a collection of **distinct** objects.

Comment: @morbusg ok, what’s your point ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know all the values in the array before you start.

The solution you are looking for is purely is a mathematical one.

The set is 1 to n, thus all items in the set sum to `sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`

Thus if there is a duplicate in an array `a` that contains the set of `1` to `a.length` then that duplicate must be the sum of all values subtract the sum of the unique values.

```
function findDuplicate(arr) {
    var sum = 0, sumArr = 0, i = arr.length;
    while (i--) { 
        sum += i;
        sumArr += arr[i];
    }
    return sumArr - sum;
}
```

or

```
function findDuplicate(arr) {
    var res = 0, i = arr.length;
    while (i--) { res += i - arr[i] }
    return -res;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.... wait a minute. The task says the elements in the array are members of the set of natural numbers {1..n}. But it doesn't say that the elements consists of consecutive numbers from 1 to n. For example this could also be a valid input: `const lst = [1, 3, 4,7,8,7] `

Comment: @thadeuszlay the *"set {1, 2, ..., n}."* means all values from 1 to and including n else it would be a subset of the set *"set {1, 2, ..., n}."* which contains some of the values. If array length is n + 1 then the array must contain the set `{1,2,..., n}`

Comment: I see. What is your opinion about this solution:
`const findDuplicate = arr => arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0) - ((arr.length - 1)*(arr.length) / 2 );`

Comment: One downside of your algorithm is that it runs till the end of the array even though it may have come across the duplicate already.

Comment: @thadeuszlay I assume that the items are not in order, that means that worst case will always requires stepping over all items. Your (comment) reduce version is just as valid

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a big fan of the functional solution for following reasons:

1. the pointless use of the `some()` method, because its callback always returns `false`. This is this possibly an error? The call would short-circuit, if `Boolean(ret = x)` weren't negated. But even then `some()` would be the wrong choice, because it's just used for short-circuiting. I believe `find()` would be a better choice.
2. the conditional expression together with `Boolean(...)` expressions are a bit if a crutch. The conditional expression seems to be only used to be shorter that an full `if`, but that requires `Boolean()`, so that it still returns a boolean value needed for `some()`.

Using `find()` I've come up with

```
const findDuplicate = lst => {
  const set = new Set();
  return lst.find(
    x => set.has(x) || !set.add(x)
  );
};
```

However I do admit it may be a bit cryptic.